# can't retrieve associated records of another table on rails using Active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have one table called Candidates, and it's model is defined like this

```
Candidates:
 has_many :candidate_jobs

SQL TABLE

    id
-----------------
    other fields
```

and a second table CandidateJobs(sql table candidate_jobs) with a model defined like this

```
class CandidateJobsController < ApplicationController

  belongs_to :candidate


SQL TABLE

     id
------------
candidate_id
other fields
```

I have records already set up in order for the two tables to match, I went to the rails console and I was able to retrieve the data I needed:

```
@result=CandidateJob.includes(:candidate).where("candidate_id=1")
```

which gives me the correct result but that seems wrong. I want to be able to make statements like

```
@candidate=Candidate.find(1)
@jobs=candidate.candidateJobs
```

and retrieve all the jobs associated to that candidate without have to make that inverse query I told you about in the previous paragraph. I want to be able to write the code from the side of the candidates that holds the jobs, not the other way around. What am I doing wrong?. Thank you so much, I been like 15 hours learning a lot about activeRecord but I couldn't manage to make queries from that perspective

Comment: With the exception of the camel-cased `candidateJobs` needing to be `candidate_jobs`, your version looks correct to me. Running `candidate.candidate_jobs.to_sql` will show you the SQL `ActiveRecord` generates, which can be useful in debugging queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look up the [`has_many` / `belongs_to`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association) association:

```
#app/models/candidate.rb
class Candidate < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :candidate_jobs
end

#app/models/candidate_job.rb
class CandidateJob < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :candidate
end
```

This will give you the ability to look up:

```
@candidate = Candidate.find 1
@jobs      = @candidate.candidate_jobs
```

--

ActiveRecord makes the whole process very simple.

Comment: This was the solution my friend. I tohught I had to write @candidate.candidateJobs.....but it seems it's like you spell it with the underscore. I just tried it in the console and it works wonders. how would I have to write it if I had a  has_one in the candidate model  and a belongs_to in the candidate_job model??   job=candidate.candidate_job ???

Comment: The difference is that only constants (classes etc) should be referenced with [CamelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase); variables should be referenced with [snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case)